# Selenium loop until attribute is found

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to refresh a website until the innertext/innerhtml of and element has changed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/smnsc/Desktop/bot/driver/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://cybersole.io/')


while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('purchase-button')
        driver.__getattribute__('Purchase £300')
        break
    except (NoSuchElementException):
        wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        waitUntil = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="purchase-button"]')))
        driver.__getattribute__('Sold Out £300')
        driver.refresh()
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: the website doesnt refresh

Comment: The code seems to be accidently formatted onto one line after the `while True:` so its hard to read, and I don't know selinium...but I suspect your problem may be it is blocking on your wait.until method. Maybe there is an option in that method to poll instead of block.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire

`while True:
 try:
  driver.find_element_by_id('purchase-button')
  driver.__getattribute__('Purchase £300')
  break
 except (NoSuchElementException):
  wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  waitUntil = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="purchase-button"]')))
  driver.__getattribute__('Sold Out £300')
  driver.refresh()`

Comment: Thanks for formatting code. Are you sure its not throwing the exception and then making it to the wait.until(...) call and waiting forever there?

Comment: @SimonSchiller Please share HTML code for `purchase-button` you mean.

Comment: please show the full code , python aswell as html .

Comment: add print statements n see which variables are actually printign the elements tat you're expecting .

Comment: @frianH `<div class="header-button" id="purchase-button"><span>Sold Out £300</span></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
driver.get('https://cybersole.io/')

text_before = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="purchase-button"]//span[text()!=""]'))).text
print(text_before)

while True:
    try:
        text_changed = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="purchase-button"]//span[text()!=' +text_before +']'))).text
        print(text_changed)
    except Exception:
        print("The text hasn't changed")
        driver.refresh()
```

Be carefully, because it has not been given a condition, the code above will continue to loop without stopping until the text changes.

Comment: ye it seems to work. im new to python or to coding in general. sooo i guess the "text" after '//span[' would be the thing i would have to change into the text that will get shown if the product is available. or am i wrong? xd

Comment: @SimonSchiller yes right, you can change the text according you want, but it refer to same element in the question. Btw, if your issue has solved by this answer, don't forget to accept this answer with click `√` icon.

Comment: @SimonSchiller if you want specific text, you can change this function `text()!=` to be `text()=`, just remove `!`.

Comment: well the purchase button got 2 text. 1. "Sold Out £300" and 2. "Purchase £300". somehow it doesnt print out "text hasnt changed" anymore after i put in these two texts. but it should print it out until yk the text has changed. so idk. maybe im putting these words in the wrong way

Comment: @SimonSchiller if you put `text_before ='blabla'`, it will not bring the code to the `except Exception:` block, because `text_changed = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="purchase-button"]//span[text()!=' +text_before +']'))).text` success to found.